# How to store package-specific settings in R: options() vs. ReferenceClasses

Tags: r

I'm just thinking out loud about this one. So far I was saving all package-specific settings in `options`. I have some experience with `ReferenceClass`es (thanks to `Rook`), and I've seen that `knitr` uses RC to save package-specific staff. I'd like to know more about pros/cons of both approaches. Or maybe you'd like to recommend another approach (e.g. sourcing R file located in `getwd()` on startup, much like `devtools` and `.Rpackages`)?

Ideas?

Comment: The devtools use case is slightly different - it needs to maintain options across sessions, not just within a session.

Comment: Maybe I am a version behind, but in knitr 0.4 I just see use of  environments and no ReferenceClasses.

Comment: well... what do you know... =) It's my speak-before-think syndrome again! Or is it just do-not-think syndrome?

Comment: Is there actually some kind of "solution" to this question/thinking? I am having the same issue and I am not sure what to choose.

Answer (score 9):

You can also store options in an `environment` stored at the top-level of your package. That may be closest to `options()` use, while avoiding the global variable.

Comment: Ah, yeah... that too! Would you prefer that over `options` and why? =)

Comment: +1 -- see `library(foreach); foreach:::.foreachGlobals` for example.

Comment: @aL3xa: as I said, it avoids a global, and hence a possible (if unlikely) clash, or side-effect, or clobbering.

Comment: Isn't a reference class singleton instance defined at the top level of the package, with defined api, a better solution than an ad-hoc environment?

Comment: Martin, do you have a favorite example package doing that I should look at?