# Why are inheritance relationships of R5 classes not defined during R package .onLoad()?

Tags: r, reference-class

I'm trying to initialize and store some package specific information when a package is first loaded and have found a lot of good information on ways to do this in [How to store some package specific information in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913905/how-to-store-package-specific-settings-in-r-options-vs-referenceclasses) and [How to run some code on load of package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223601/r-how-to-run-some-code-on-load-of-package). However, one function I want to call during package loading verifies the inheritance relationships of several classes defined in the package, but this returns different results from what I would have expected. I can come up with different ways to work around this problem but I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong and was hoping someone could explain it to me.

A minimal example of the package source code to reproduce the problem follows.

```
# package reference classes
setClass("myclass", representation(value = "numeric"), 
                    prototype = prototype(value = 42))
setClass("myderivedclass", contains = "myclass")

# package on load function
.onLoad <- function(lib, pkg){  
    if (!extends("myderivedclass", "myclass")) {
        warning("something's not right")
    }
}
```

Now during package `.onLoad`, `extends("myderivedclass", "myclass")` evaluates to `FALSE` (triggering the warning), but of course once the package is loaded it evaluates to `TRUE`, which is what I would have expected. Initializing objects with either class during `.onLoad` works just fine so it's not that the class definitions aren't loaded yet.

Thank you very much for any help on how I should be doing this kind of test during `.onLoad` or what I might have misunderstood about inheritance here.

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
```

Comment: I _think_ you want to use `setLoadAction`, for the reasons outlined on it's help page and in the comments by John Chambers in [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/check-warning-with-onLoad-and-setClass-td4677489.html)

Comment: Thank you, using ```setLoadAction``` does solve the problem! I've also experimented some more and found using ```.onAttach``` instead of ```.onLoad``` works as well. Do you know what is the recommended approach? (```.onAttach``` vs. ```setLoadAction``` ?)

Comment: Since Chambers (a creator of the S language, and of the S4 and reference class system) says to use setLoadAction, I'd take that as the recommendation!

Comment: good point, advice well taken, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this is how it worked with `setLoadAction` instead of `.onLoad`

```
setLoadActions(function(ns) {
    if (!extends("myderivedclass", "myclass")) {
        warning("something's not right")
    } else {
        message("everything all right")
    }
})
```

In this way, `extends("myderivedclass", "myclass")`properly evaluates to `TRUE` during package loading.